# malloc within constructor safe?

Tags: c++

If I allocate memory with `malloc` (or `new`/`new[]`) within a class constructor, is that bit of memory safe from being overwritten?

```
class stack {
  private:
    int * stackPointer;
  public:
    stack (int size) {
      stackPointer = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * stackSize);
    }
    int peek (int pos) {
      return *(stackPointer + pos); //pos < size
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is that bit of memory safe from being overwritten?" ?

Comment: If you `malloc` an array within a function and return a pointer to the array, that is not safe because that array goes out of scope when the function returns and can be overwritten.

Comment: That's not true. Dynamically allocated memory does not go out of scope. You're confusing it with returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: one suggestion use `reinterpret_cast<int *>`, C++ style casting.

Comment: its safeish (we havent seen your other methods) - but dont do it, use std::vector<int>, thats safe, easy and well understood

Comment: @interjay Yes, sorry I meant a local variable, eg `char str[9] = malloc (9); return str;`

Comment: @texasflood That wouldn't even compile. What is not allowed is: `char str[9] = "wrong"; return str;` No malloc here.

Comment: @interjay Yes you're right, my bad!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`malloc`/`new` within a constructor is safe, *provided you follow the rule of three*. With `malloc`/`new` you now have a resource that you have to explicitly take care to release at the right times.

Therefore: you must define a copy constructor, an assignment operator, and a destructor that will `free` the memory. If you don't, the class can be misused and cause you a lot of problems.

If you want to avoid having to define these extra functions, use `std::vector` instead, which handles them for you.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to define the copy constructor and assignment operator. Deleting them is the simplest way to make the class safe, if you don't need it to be copyable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any memory that you allocate using `malloc()` is safely yours. And it will not be overwritten except by your code (whether intentionally or from a bug).

Answer (score 0):

The language protections in C++ are just that, language protections.

If you are doing some fancy C pointer games, you can eventually find and overwrite the allocated memory.  It's considered the **exact opposite** of best practice, but it can happen.

As such, the "protection" is much like "hiding".  Malloc within a constructor will return pointers that are "hidden" based on the exposure the surrounding class decides to allow, but they are not protected in the sense of "memory fencing" or the other more expensive operations that an operating system / hardware platform might impose between programs.

As far as it being "safe", I wouldn't recommend the practice, mostly because there is a chance you don't exit the constructor.  If you fail within the constructor, attempting to do proper memory cleanup of any mallocs that might have succeeded would be a very hard bit of programming to verify it worked correctly.  Use `new` instead, and put your memory in an object, and that way at least in failure conditions, you will have only one memory allocation technique to worry about.

Malloc with C++ means you have two memory allocation techniques, and two different ways they can cross-interact.  That's four scenarios to deal with, and odds are you'll never get around to testing them all sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's safe from being overwritten by others as long as you don't pass handle to that memory to outside world in any of possible manner. That way you can localize the manipulation of that memory to class members only.

However, you can't be 100% sure on that as other programmer could write a program in a way which could corrupt your memory.For e.g passing out of bound index to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

No writable memory is safe from being overwritten within a C or C++ program. The allocation functions establish a claim over a memory and it is the program's responsibility to respect these claims.